# UIInterpolatingMotionEffect works randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm adding a `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` to some views in `UITableViewCell`s this way:

```
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
horizontalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-horizontal);
horizontalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(horizontal);
verticalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-vertical);
verticalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(vertical);

UIMotionEffectGroup *effectsGroup = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
effectsGroup.motionEffects = @[horizontalEffect, verticalEffect];

[view addMotionEffect:effectsGroup];
```

The problem is that the effect  only appears randomly, where some views get the effect and some don't. After pushing a view controller and going back, some others work and some others don't.

Is there something I'm missing? Should the effect be applied every time the cell is reused?

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath or where?

Comment: More or less, I add the motion effect when I create the cell.

Comment: Try to not use a UIMotioneffectGroup but just add the two motions effects like this: [view addMotionEffect:horizontalEffect]; and [view addMotionEffect:verticalEffect];

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Same here (nearly). Did manage to fix this one?

Comment: Question is "Did YOU manage to fix it?"

Comment: No, actually I was never able to fix this.

Comment: Do you try to apply the motion to custom views which class overrides drawRect? I had a problem with the these and add the motion effect in drawRect now - seems to work better, but still miss it on some views from time to time

Comment: Facing the same issue. I can confirm that the view on each cell, on which the motion effect is to be added, does contain the effect in it's motionEffects array, but for some reason does not reflect during runtime.

Comment: Was experiencing the same issue, I think I've found a fix - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by forcing a redraw of all the cells - using reloadSections:withRowAnimation: will likely work for most people (or a similar method), although for me I ultimately had to write my own cell inits and reuse code that let me keep a reference to every created cell in a mutable array, and then clear that array and build from scratch when I chose to. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Had to completely remove my previous answer, because I have finally found a better solution.

It looks like iOS7/8 messes with the motion effects of the views inside the table/collection views once the cell is redrawn / dequeued. You need to make sure your motion effect are set up / updated after the cell is dequeued / set up.

To properly do so, you need to move your motion effect logic to the `-layoutSubviews` method.
Then just send the `[self setNeedsLayout]` message within your constructor and methods, which you use to update the cell contents after the cell is dequeued and updated.

This solved the issue completely for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `UICollectionView`, I was experiencing the same problem. After pushing a new controller, then going back to the `UICollectionView`, some of my cells' `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`s stopped functioning, but were still listed on the view's `motionEffects` property.

**Solution:**
I called to setup my motion effects in `-layoutSubviews`, and whenever configuring the cell, I called `-setNeedsLayout` to ensure `-layoutSubviews` was called.

Additionally, every time I setup my motion effects, I would remove the previous motion effects. This was key.

Here's the method I called in `-layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)applyInterpolatingMotionEffectToView:(UIView *)view withParallaxLimit:(CGFloat)limit
{
    NSArray *effects = view.motionEffects;
    for (UIMotionEffect *motionEffect in effects)
    {
        [view removeMotionEffect:motionEffect];
    }

    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *effectX = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath: @"center.x" type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
    effectX.minimumRelativeValue = @(-limit);
    effectX.maximumRelativeValue = @(limit);

    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *effectY = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath: @"center.y" type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
    effectY.minimumRelativeValue = @(-limit);
    effectY.maximumRelativeValue = @(limit);

    [view addMotionEffect: effectX];
    [view addMotionEffect: effectY];
}
```

Hope it helps! Also, running on iOS 9.