# Parallax effect with UIMotionEffect not working

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, parallax, uimotioneffect

My parallax effect for `UIView` is not working at all. I need something like a moving background image on iPhone tilt (pseudo-3D).

```
let horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -50
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 50

let verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: .TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -50
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 50

let motionEffectGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()
motionEffectGroup.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]

imageView.addMotionEffect(motionEffectGroup)
```

I've tried to use this code. I've read https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-a-parallax-effect-in-uikit but my `imageView` remains static.

I'm using Xcode 11, iOS 13.

Comment: Is the `imageView` that you are applying the effect to a part of a table or a collection view? If so, you might want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319722/uiinterpolatingmotioneffect-works-randomly

Comment: No, it's just the regular UIImageView, constrained to superview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code that you have shared, one thing that I noticed is that you are using capital `T` in the enums `.TiltAlongHorizontalAxis` and `.TiltAlongVerticalAxis`, which don't compile (at least on Xcode 11.4.1) -> those need to be changed to lowercase `T`.

Apple's documentation for those enums is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterpolatingmotioneffect/effecttype).

Other than that, I don't see any problems with the code that you shared. In fact I created a sample project with a simple `imageView` in the view to which I added constraints so that it fills up the entire space of its superview.

I then added the motion effects code that you shared, and ran it on an actual device (iPad Pro). It worked perfectly.

Could you check a few things that might be a source of the problem:

- Double check that `Settings` > `Accessibility` > `Motion` > `Reduce Motion` is not turned on. Because if it is turned on, then `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` won't work.
- Test that the accelerometer of the device that you are testing on actually works. Or better still, use another device to test it. (This won't work on the simulator).
- If you are editing the frame of the `imageView` in code anywhere (or especially in `viewWillLayout` / `viewDidLayout`), you shouldn't be doing that.

In any case, if none of these things help you to fix your problem, can you create a simple sample project which demonstrates the bug and post it on Github? I can try to help if I can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks a LOT!!!!! It works

Double check that Settings > Accessibility > Motion > Reduce Motion is not turned on. Because if it is turned on, then UIInterpolatingMotionEffect won't work.